# Webflow integration with React

Tags: reactjs, webflow

I am trying to make a website using webflow, and when I try to export my code it works in the project folder that I downloaded from webflow.  However, when I created a react app (create-react-app) and copied the `styles`, `js`, `fonts`, `images` folders into the public folder and copy the HTML into a react component, the content is there but not the animations.  One of my animations is that when you scroll down the page some text will appear.  I have searched on the webflow forums and several people had this problem too but haven't gotten an answer to fix the problem.

Comment: Try using https://npm.io/package/webflow-react. It will convert your Vanila JS webflow website to a ReactJS website.

Comment: Searching on Google, `AppFairy` is recommended. See: https://medium.com/the-guild/how-to-create-a-react-app-out-of-a-webflow-project-309b696a0533 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hJe6pZld0o&ab_channel=EytanManor

Comment: You could also check Desech Studio that integrates natively with react. Check this repository to see more details https://github.com/desech/studio-react